# Indexing on a column of a huge database that can take only 3 possible values

Tags: database, indexing, db2

I am trying to understand if it is worth from a performance point of view in order to create an index on a column of a huge table (about 90 million records in total).

What I am trying to achieve is fast filtering on the indexed column. The column to be indexed can have only 3 possible values and as per my requirement I have to fetch data on a regular basis with two of those values. This comes out to about 45 million records (half the table size).

Does it make any sense to create an index on a column that can have only 3 possible values and you need to retrieve data with two values amongst them ? Also, will creating this index improve performance of my query with WHERE clause on the column ?

Comment: Is the table organized by row or by column?  If it is a table organized by row, is row compression enabled?  Do other columns in the table also have a small number of discrete values?  When asking performance question, the answer often is "it depends" (on lots of factors that you do not mention in your question). So copy the data to a non-prod environment and compare the performance...and compare access plans...

Comment: okay.. what about creating index ? Is it advisable to create an index on a column with only 3 possible values ?

Comment: Regular index won't help. If your table is row organized, then use range partitioning for such a small number of distinct rows with their values known beforehand.

Comment: It depends. The filtering capacity of the index won't be normally useful. It can be useful,  when the distribution of values is very skewed (e.g. 99.9% of cases are "closed", and 0.1% of cases are "open"). In any case, the coverage capacity of the index can still be valuable. Do you want to retrieve most/all the columns or just a small subset of them?

Comment: I want to retrieve all the columns matching the criteria